# How to exclude certain char from being used as a variable name in production build?

Tags: rollup, vite

After build, one of my variables is getting renamed to $ char. I use built code in Jquery project and this variable called $ causes errors. How can I exclude $ sign from being used as variable in the production files?
This is how the production code looke like even though I use nowhere $ sign:

```
function $(e,t){e.value=t==null?"":t}
```

How can exclude $ sign from being used as variable or function name?